# Facebook dialogs are not displaying to there full height?

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using different facebook dialog boxes on my external website(a kind of facebook application) for tasks like posting to feed, Sending app requests etc. Earlier all dialogs were displaying properly but from last couple of days I have been experiencing display issues as dialog are not displaying to there full height.

I have tested on Chrome, Firefox and Safari browsers, at all places same issue.I even asked some of my friends to check at there places, as a result they are also facing the same.

Here is the snapshot link:
[image: screenshot of apprequest dialog]

Here is the code to one apprequest dialog, I m using:

```js
<body onLoad="warmup();">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

function sendRequest(type) {


var request = {
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Hey! I Just Wanted You To Fill My Slambook.',
    data: type,
        title: 'Select friends'

};      

FB.init({ 
       appId:'xxxxxxxxx', cookie:true, 
       status:true, xfbml:true 
     });

    FB.ui(request, function (response) {
        if (response && response.request_ids) {


           document.getElementById('sent').style.display='block';
        } else {


        }
    })
}


function warmup(){
FB.init({ 
       appId:'xxxxxxxxx', cookie:true, 
       status:true, xfbml:true
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little trick that work for me:

```
var HACKAppRequests = {
    id_interval:0,
    busca:function(){
        var i,fb_root,iframe;

        try{
            fb_root = document.getElementById('fb-root');
            iframe = fb_root.getElementsByTagName('IFRAME');

            recorre_iframe:
            for(i=0;i<iframe.length;i++){
                if(iframe[i].className=='FB_UI_Dialog'){
                    clearInterval(HACKAppRequests.id_interval);
                    iframe[i].style.height = '550px';
                    break recorre_iframe;
                };
            };
        } catch(err){};
    }
};
```

FACEBOOK CALL

```
function buscaAmigosFB(){
    FB.ui({method:'apprequests',
        title:'Esto es sólo para TI',
        message:'He decidido comenzar a escribir una historia. ¿Te atreves a escribirla conmigo ;D?',
        max_recipients:1
    },someFunction);

// RESIZE
HACKAppRequests.id_interval = setInterval(HACKAppRequests.busca,250);
};
```

Comment: Joshua Thanks for reply!!
Facebook fixed it!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that will be fixed soon: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194725433940802